# Gradle - Create .properties file before / as part of each build and include it into JAR

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, properties-file

I want Gradle to write a `version.properties` file into my Java classpath whenever I build the project.

I have a task like this

```
task createVersionPropertiesFile()  {
    def outputFile = new File(projectDir, "src/main/java/org/example/lpimport/version.properties")
    outputs.file outputFile
    doLast {
        outputFile.text = 
        """# generated by Gradle
version=$version
revision=${getSvnRevision()}
buildtime=${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())}
"""
    }
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

And I include it like this:

```
build.dependsOn createVersionPropertiesFile
```

When I run the Gradle `build` task in Eclipse, the file is created as expected! ✅

If I run my application in Eclipse, the generated `version.properties` file can be loaded by my application. ✅

```
props.load( Main.class.getResourceAsStream( "version.properties" ) );
```

But the `version.properties` file will **not** be part of the built `myproject-1.0.0.jar` inside the `myproject-1.0.0.zip` distribution, although it resides in a normal class path package. ❌

How can I make Gradle include the on-the-fly generated `version.properties` inside the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making two changes:

- Write the `.properties` file to `src/main/resources` instead of `src/main/java`:

  ```
  def outputFile = new File(projectDir, "src/main/resources/org/example/lpimport/version.properties")
  ```
- Make the `compileJava` task depend on my custom task:

  ```
  compileJava.dependsOn createVersionPropertiesFile
  ```

It seems the `.properties` file is ignored by Gradle (by its jar task??) if it resides below `src/main/java`.

Now it works and my built and packaged application can display its version properties on startup.

Comment: Since you were able to seolve this, I'd request if you could share the sample/code of how that looks like in the `gradle` file